# Add a backslash in the string using format

Tags: python, string, literals

I have added a backslash after mod which I need to execute using subprocess but while printing the command name it shows double backslash using pdb.

```
command = "ffmpeg -i {} -vf 'select=not(mod(n\,{}))' -vsync -vfr -q:v 2 {} 2>NUL".format(vid, args.nfps, viddir + "/%06d.png")
subprocess.call(command,shell=True)
(Pdb) command
"ffmpeg -i /home/ashutosh/Music/2020-07-24/DV1/0001.mp4 -vf 'select=not(mod(n\\,60))' -vsync -vfr -q:v 2 /home/ashutosh/Music/2020-07-24/DV1/0001/%06d.png 2>NUL"
```

The output should be like

```
"ffmpeg -i /home/ashutosh/Music/2020-07-24/DV1/0001.mp4 -vf 'select=not(mod(n\,60))' -vsync -vfr -q:v 2 /home/ashutosh/Music/2020-07-24/DV1/0001/%06d.png 2>NUL"
```

I tried to add backslash in the format but then more backslashes get added.

Anyway to code this around so that I get a single backslash.

Comment: Please update your question with the output you require.

Answer (score 1):

There’s only a single backslash. You can confirm this via `print(command)`. The reason you’re seeing two backslashes is that pdb displays the value as a Python string inside code, and backslashes generally need to be escaped in strings in Python — in fact, you shouldn’t write `"…\,…"` in your code, you should write `"…\\,…"`. But since `\,` isn’t a [known escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), Python “lets this slide”, so to speak.

But beware that in general using `\` inside a string may have a special meaning, and if you want to use a literal backslash you either need to escape it (i.e. write `\\`) or you need to use a raw string literal (`r"…"`).

Comment: Yeah you are correct, while printing it takes single backslash but the thing is that the double backslash string goes into the subprocess call which doesn't get executed as per the requirement. How do I escape that ?

Comment: @AshutoshMishra There is not a double-backslash string. It is purely how it is being represented when you just type `command`. Did you try `print(command)` as Konrad suggested?

Comment: print(command) works in the way Konrad said but the thing is I don't print it. I have to send it to subprocess for execution which still takes the string command with two backslashes.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra No, it definitely, 100% doesn’t. What makes you think so? — That said, you’re apparently using Windows, where `shell=True` is definitely [not recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor). Use `shell=False` and pass separate arguments to the `subprocess.call` function, instead of a command string.

Comment: `shell=True` is pretty much not recommended on any system...

Comment: @sabik True, but it’s also not as harmful on other systems as it is on Windows, because the shell being used is (somewhat) better specified. And for some commands, using `shell=True` is quite a bit easier than either creating an intermediate script file or passing arguments via `sh -c` …. That said, it’s usefulness is definitely limited.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra Why do you think that the string contains two backslashes?

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Yeah, if you're going to create an intermediate script file or explicitly invoking `sh -c`, you might as well use `shell=True`; in the majority of circumstances, though, you're invoking one command with a Python-generated list of arguments, at which point the shell is superfluous and can only hurt.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, there is in fact only a single backslash, not two.

A better solution than playing with backslashes would be to omit the `shell=True` and pass the `ffmpeg` command line as a list.

```
command = [
    "ffmpeg", "-i", vid, "-vf", r"select=not(mod(n\,{}))".format(args.nfps), 
    "-vsync", "-vfr", "-q:v", "2", os.path.join(viddir, "%06d.png"),
]
subprocess.call(command, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

That way you avoid having another component (the shell), and if any parts of the command ever come from a user, you'll also avoid creating a security hole. Generally speaking, it's better to avoid `shell=True` if at all possible.

Comment: There should be a \  after n in the mod operation. If you add \ in that and do print(command) you can see that there are two backslashes coming. The backslash is important to sample every nth frame.

Comment: Ah, thanks; fixed in the answer (and added the `r"` prefix). Do note that `print(command)` will add an extra backslash of its own that's not actually in the variable (and won't be passed to `ffmpeg`), though.

Comment: Still I am getting \\ instead of \. Both using print and simply putting the variable name on Python shell

Comment: Yes, printing out a list or putting the variable name in Python shell both turn \ into \\. It's not actually in the string. You can check by setting `s=r'foo\bar'` and printing `len(s)` - you'll see that it's 7 characters, not 8, even though outputting `s` will show as `"foo\\bar"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a literal backslash in a string, then your options are either to use a raw string (note the `r` before the opening `'`):

```
>>> s = r'foo\bar'
>>> print(s)
foo\bar
```

or to quote the backslash using an extra backslash:

```
>>> s = 'foo\\bar'
>>> print(s)
foo\bar
```

The best way to see what you have is to use `print`.

Be aware that if instead of using `print`, you display the contents of the string just by typing the variable name in an interactive session (including in `pdb`), then this will be equivalent of `print(repr(s))` - in other words what it prints will be essentially the expression that would need to be used in Python source code in order to recover the original string.  This would therefore include the extra backslash as shown above:

```
>>> s
'foo\\bar'

>>> print(repr(s))
'foo\\bar'
```

but it does *not* imply that the string actually contains two backslashes.

Comment: You can check `len(s)` to see that it only contains 7 characters.